# Problem with implementation of typed interfaces that use each other

Tags: c#, mvvm, interface

I have two typed interfaces

```
public interface IComponentAreaModel<T>
public interface IComponentAreaViewModel<T>
```

The interface for the view model has a property 'Model' defined which is of the type of the interface for the model:

```
IComponentAreaModel<T> Model { get; }
```

In my actual implementation I have a model that implements the 'IComponentAreaModel' interface which works fine:

```
public class ArticleModel : IComponentAreaModel<Article>
```

Then I implement the view model as follows:

```
public class ArticleViewModel : IComponentAreaViewModel<Article>
        {
            public ArticleModel Model { get; }
        }
```

And here the compiler tells me that the member 'Model' does not have the matching return type. To fix this, I would have to implement the view model as follows:

```
public class ArticleViewModel : IComponentAreaViewModel<Article>
{
    public IComponentAreaModel<Article> Model { get; }
}
```

But this sucks as my ArticleModel class has some additional methods and stuff that are not part of the IComponentAreaModel. So when I wanted to use these methods through the property within my ArticleViewModel, then I would have to cast the interface object to the actual object.

Is there a way to tell the compiler that my ArticleModel implements the IComponentAreaModel and therefore is sufficient as Model for the IComponentAreaViewModel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how do you use these interfaces. At least, there are three options.

Option 1. Use field inside implementation:

```
public class ArticleViewModel : IComponentAreaViewModel<Article>
{
    // use this field, when you need ArticleModel
    private readonly ArticleModel model;

    // TODO: initialize model somehow

    public IComponentAreaModel<Article> Model => model;
}
```

Option 2. Use explicit interface implementation:

```
public class ArticleViewModel : IComponentAreaViewModel<Article>
{
    // use this property, when you need ArticleModel
    public ArticleModel Model { get; }

    IComponentAreaModel<Article> IComponentAreaViewModel<Article>.Model => Model;
}
```

Option 3. Add the 2nd type parameter to view model interface. Will add complexity, especially if you want to use `IComponentAreaViewModel<>` with another generic types:

```
public interface IComponentAreaViewModel<T, TModel>
    where TModel : IComponentAreaModel<T>
{
    TModel Model { get; }
}

public class ArticleViewModel : IComponentAreaViewModel<Article, ArticleModel>
{
    public ArticleModel Model { get; }
}
```

Comment: Option 3 was exactly what I was looking for.
I could not have solved this on my own - Thanks!!!!!